# How to assign utube video url to android media player

Tags: android

I want that when i will pass the **utube url** to media player it will automatically load the video and play in it.
Example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAG8e_53le4 
 This type of url i want to play in android media player

Comment: Don't be lazy dude... you can write *youtube*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to play YouTube video in VideoView, you need rtsp url from youtube.
You can get the rtsp from Youtube Gdata feed. Although I find it quite strange that sometime the rtsp isn't available in the feed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It starts when the activity is created.

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(StevenBActivity.this, "", "Buffering video...", true);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

                 //video "DON'T DO IT" 1,315 views
     video_url = "rtsp://v2.cache4.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwlPMIWk2hSzNRMYJCAkFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3Jlc3VsdHNg6KnB9MbH8sVODA==/0/0/0/video.3gp";
                 //http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJNzBQvJpUI&list=UUy_BjNhdQh9-bfRuzuk53pg&index=9&feature=plcp
        try {
                final VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
                mediaController = new MediaController(StevenBActivity.this);
                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                // Set video link (mp4 format )
                Uri video = Uri.parse(video_url);
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.setVideoURI(video);

                videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                       videoView.start();
                    }
                });

             }catch(Exception e){
                  progressDialog.dismiss();
                 System.out.println("Video Play Error :"+e.getMessage());
             }

}
```